# iOS WKWebView HTML5 Video Black Screen on Resume

Tags: ios, html, ios9, wkwebview

I'm trying to play some locally downloaded videos on iOS using WKWebView. I copy the files into 'tmp/www' and they play fine. The issue I have is if I resign my activity using home button and bring it back, the video will resume playing but the screen will be black (there is audio).

The video readyState is 4 so I'm not sure what is wrong. If I trigger a new `load()` on the video the screen comes back but I'd like NOT to have to do that - is there anything in the media player I can query to tell me it's in this messed up date?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I have a similar issue but with phonegap on iOS. Unfortunately it happens rarely so I was not able to solve it yet.

Comment: similar issue; may be WKWebView bug?